# How solve error ApplicationRole "does not contain a constructor that takes arguments 1. [DbInitialize]?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I creatred class ApplicationRole and inherited from IdentityRole

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ProjDAL.Entities
{
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {

    }
}
```

When i trying add new roles i get error:

```
if (await _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("Quality Manager") == null)
{
    await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole("Quality Manager"));
}
```

'ApplicationRole "does not contain a constructor that takes arguments 1. [DbInitialize]

**UPDATE:**

I have implemented constructor:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {
        public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName)
        {
        }
    }
```

but now get error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No suitable constructor found for entity 
type 'ApplicationRole'. The following constructors had parameters that could 
not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'roleName' 
in ApplicationRole(string roleName).
```

Comment: Your class doesn't have a constructor?

Comment: Probably you should add `public ApplicationRole(string roleName)` and put the logic there. If you did not declare any parameters, by default the class uses parameterless constructor.

Comment: Inherited doesn't mean it inherited it's constructor. You need to create the constructor and use `base()`

Comment: Nothing, base() will handle whatever the parent has implemented. `public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName) {}`

Comment: I have updated question with code constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short Answer :** Change your code as below

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string>
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName)
    {
    }
}
```

**Long Version :**

> 'ApplicationRole "does not contain a constructor that takes arguments 1. [DbInitialize]`

The first error occurs because you're trying to create a new role by

```
new ApplicationRole("Quality Manager")
```

However, there's no constructor that accepts a single string as parameter:

```
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
    {

    }
```

So it complains that

> does not contain a constructor that takes arguments 1. [DbInitialize]

Note **when there's no explicit constructor, C# will [create one by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors#default-constructors) for you**.

However, if you add a constructor as below :

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName)
    {
    }
}
```

**There will be only one constructor which accepts a `string` as `roleName`**. Note that means **there is no constructor that takes no arguments**. As this constructor (that takes no arguments) is used by the `Identity` internally, it complains that `No suitable constructor found for entity type 'ApplicationRole'`.

As a result, if you would like to create a `ApplicationRole` by:

```
new ApplicationRole("Quality Manager")
```

you need create both `ApplicationRole()` and `ApplicationRole(string roleName)` constructors.